# How to align one flex item to top of container while others follow justify-content: center?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a two item grid, with the first item being a flex container.

html:

```
  <div class = "grid">
     <div class="flex">
      <h1>Anchor To Top?</h1>
      <div>item</div>
      <div>item</div>
      <div>item</div>
      <div>item</div>
      <div>item</div>
   </div>

   <div class = "other-grid-item">
   Other grid item
   </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  height: 100vh;
}
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

You can see the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/tc9kdhb1/3/ . Is there a way I can tell the `h1` to remain positioned at the top of the `flex` container, while the other flex items get positioned in the center of the remaining space?

I attempted to use `position: absoltute` on the `h1` but then the element no longer fits in the container properly. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You already achieved that with your code; you just forgot to align the text.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  height: 100vh;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="flex">
    <h1>Anchor To Top?</h1>

    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
  </div>

  <div class="other-grid-item">
    Other grid item
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's convenient to you, you can wrap other divs in a parent div and give it `flex: 1`.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  height: 100vh;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: blue;
}

.other-grid-item {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="flex">
    <h1>Anchor To Top?</h1>
    
    <div class="content">
      <div>item</div>
      <div>item</div>
      <div>item</div>
      <div>item</div>
      <div>item</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="other-grid-item">
    Other grid item
  </div>
</div>
```